# Trace 0 and Norm 1 elements in Finite fields

Tags: normed-spaces, finite-fields, trace-map

Let $F_q$ and $F_{q^{\ell}}$ be the finite fields with $q, q^{\ell}$ elements respectively, where $\ell \ge 3$ is a prime and $\gcd(\ell, q)=1$. 
 I have the following question:

Does there exist $\ell, q\;$ (as above) and an element $\alpha \in F_{q^{\ell}}$ such that $Tr_{F_{q^{\ell}}/F_q}(\alpha)= 0$ and $N_{F_{q^{\ell}}/F_q}(\alpha)=1$ ?

Comment: Are you asking whether there always exists such an element? There certainly can exist such an element – if $q$ is 3 mod 4, and $\ell=2$, and $\alpha$ satisfies $x^2+1=0$. But if $q$ is 1 mod 4, and $\ell=2$, then there can't be any such element.

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: I want know, there always exist such an element for any $\ell\ge 3$ (prime) with $gcd(\ell,q)=1$ ?
Can you suggest any reference regarding this ?

Comment: You should edit your question, then, so it asks what you actually want to ask.